# MySQL doesn't save whole amounts into decimal colum

Tags: mysql, sql, decimal, currency

I have these values which I need to save into MySQL (column **DECIMAL 10, 2**).

```
-500.00
-500.00
35000.00
```

When a PHP script save these values into the database and I will take a look at these saved values, there is just:

```
500.00
500.00
5000.00
```

How's it possible?

**EDIT:**

Saving into DB:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (name, address, salary) VALUES ('$name', '$address', $salary)");
```

I also tried to add apostrops to the **$salary**, but the same thing, didn't help me to save the correct value.

**EDIT 2:**

When I print out the variables with these numbers before executing the SQL query, so the values are correct. But when I print out the currently executed SQL query, there are the incorrect values...

Comment: Show us the code used to save the values into the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column definition should be `DECIMAL(10, 2)` and *not* followed by `UNSIGNED`. The missing sign could be caused by an "unsigned".

The error on 35000.00 could be an output error (`sprintf`).

**Most uniformly, you remove the first char at output.**

Maybe you tried to change one '.' in salary by nothing, removing the first character.

Comment: Well, if I try to save the value `-1.00`, this one is save correctly.

Comment: Well, I use PhpMyAdmin, not the terminal. "Most uniformly, you remove the first char at output." -> Before I save the values into the database, I printed out the variables and there is `35000.00`, not only `5000.00`.

Comment: Maybe the on-screen PhpMyAdmin representation hides the first char `-   5000.00`? Could you show an SQL query, or make a **table dump**? Two errors is too weird.

Comment: No, PhpMyAdmin doesn't hide the first char. Take a look please at the updated OP, when I print out the currently executed SQL query, so there are already bad values, but when I print out these values before  executing SQL query, they are ok.

Comment: You are sure the column is *not* defined `DECIMAL(7, 2) UNSIGNED`?

Comment: Yes, I do. The column is defined as `decimal(10,2)`. Gosh, I didn't meet problem like this before. Also I tested it on localhost and on hosting and in both cases the same.

Comment: There is a double quote missing after `$salary` in the query.

Comment: Put the query in a string `$s = "INSERT ..."` an print that variable. (Paranoya)

Comment: `INSERT INTO citizens (name, address, salary) VALUES ( 'Peter Novak', 'Hamburg, Germany', 5000.00)`... and the last value should be `35000.00`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21886/discussion-between-joop-eggen-and-user984621)